# getting this error -> dial tcp: lookup bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com on x.x.x:53: no such host

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I'm doing the bulk process, it gives us an error **tcp: lookup bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com on x.x.x:53: no such host** for most of the objects.

**Error:**
*RequestError: send request failed
caused by: Get https://bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/xyz.jpg: dial tcp: lookup bucketName.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com on x.x.x:53: no such host*

**Function in which I'm getting an error:**

`out, err := svc.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput { Bucket: aws.String(bucketName), Key: aws.String(key), })`

Please help here to resolve this issue.

```
[Error Screenshot]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctMrD.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to too many open GetObject calling. To resolve this error need to close out the Body as out.Body.Close(). That's it, and it will solve our problem mentioned above.